# How to make docker pull images in an Azure DevOps pipeline from a file.txt?

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I m trying to pull images in my pipeline in a dynamic way.
I have a file call "images.txt"
that contain:(cat images.txt would return)

```
cat images.txt
  cassadra
  python
  neo4j
```

the way to pull a image in azure pipeline is:

*that code work but its not dynamic*

```
steps:
   - bash: |
        y='python:3.8-slim' #I m using tha as var but would work  without that
        docker pull ${y}
    
    displayName: "Docker pull"
```

But when I try to do it dynamically it doesnt work anymore:

That code work im my local laptop but not in azure pipelines and in theory both should work

```
 #!/bin/bash
 filename='images.txt'
 n=1
 while read line; do
 # reading each line
 eval docker pull "$line"
 n=$((n+1))
 done < $filename
```

in Azure pipelines look like this:

```
   - bash: |
      #x='python:3.8-slim'
      filename='images.txt'
      n=1
      while read line; do
         echo "pulling image"
         echo ${line}
         n=$((n+1))
         docker pull ${line}
     done < $filename
```

but I m reciving the whole time that error: so

*invalid reference format*

it was my understanding that everything that worked on linux would work on Azure Pipelines(inside bash)
what I am not taking into account ?

Thanks in advance
Enrique

Comment: You can consider using [runtime parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) instead of reading from txt file.

Comment: Hi @HughLin-MSFT its correct !! please make it as answer and I validade it :) Thank you very much !!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I have converted the comment to answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to make docker pull images in an Azure DevOps pipeline from a
> file.txt?

For this issue, you can consider using [runtime parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) instead of reading from txt file.

Runtime parameters let you have more control over what values can be passed to a pipeline. With runtime parameters you can:

- Supply different values to scripts and tasks at runtime
- Control parameter types, ranges allowed, and defaults
- Dynamically select jobs and stages with template expressions